# smoothing imshow plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, filter, imshow

I am plotting a density of counts with imshow from matplotlib.pyplot but I'd like to have a smoother plot.

[image]

Can I apply any filter on this?

Comment: `imshow` doesn't seem to have a smooth option, so you should probably look into smoothing of the dataset itself. See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765891/image-smoothing-in-python) example

Comment: The new default interpolation in mpl 2.0 will be `'nearest'`

Comment: @tcaswell Is it really a duplicate? Although I agree that the solution is the same, I would argue that the question asked here is not duplicate of the one you reference. I can easily imagine someone searching for one of them might not find the other based on the question asked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the interpolation argument:
`ax.imshow(grid, interpolation=interp_method)`

[matplotlib demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html)

[matplotlib api](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)
[image: output]

If you manually want to handle how strong the filter is you could
do something along the lines of (scipy.ndimage has a lot of filters)

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
arr=np.zeros((20,20))
arr[0,:]=3
arr[0,0]=20
arr[19,19]=30
arr[10:12,10:12]=10

filtered_arr=gaussian_filter(arr, sigma)
plt.imshow(filtered_arr)
```

to get (from top left: raw image, sigma=1,2,3):
[image]