# How to plot heat map with interpolation in python?

Tags: python

Code Output Image
[image]

Desired Image
[[image: Desired Picture][1]]

My CSV data consists of X axis value, Y axis value and Hardness value and I wanted to plot smooth heat map rather than in boxes like.

DATA:
[image]

import cv2
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import glob
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import style
from astropy.convolution import convolve, Gaussian2DKernel
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

```
path = r"C:\Users\patels\Desktop\Ti/"

ids = os.listdir(path)
#print(ids)
for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(ids), total=len(ids)):

    
    data = pd.read_excel(path+id_)
    print(path+id_)
    
    df1 = data[['HV 0.2', 'X pos. [mm]', 'Y pos. [mm]']]

    heatmap1_data = pd.pivot_table(df1, values='HV 0.2', index=['Y pos. [mm]'], columns='X pos. [mm]') 
    
    plt.figure() #this creates a new figure on which your plot will appear

    heatmap1 = sns.heatmap(heatmap1_data, cmap="viridis", vmin=300, vmax=400)
       
    plt.title(ids[n]+'Ti Hardness Map')
```

Comment: I want my heatmap should look like the above picture

Comment: Pleae provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. providing sample (e.g. 3x3 grid) input data, (properly formatted) code which works but the result is not desired (is box like), picture of desired output etc.

Comment: Please review the changes

Comment: What about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230108/smoothing-imshow-plot-with-matplotlib)?